# trim method working in GlassFish Server but not in tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, glassfish

I'm creating a web application where the user name comes with blank space. I use method trim() to remove the spaces. This was working fine in the Glass Fish server. When i migrated the same application to a tomcat server(version 7), its pointing out error on the exact line where i use .trim() and even the .split method in not working.

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /userpage.jsp at line 195

192: <tr>
193: <%String store=(String)pageContext.getAttribute("Uname", PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);
194:                                System.out.println("scope: "+ store);
195:                                store.trim();
196:                %>
197:     <td><input type="hidden" name="email" value="<%=(String)pageContext.getAttribute("Uname", PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE)%>" /></td>
198: </tr> 


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: Share some code please

Comment: Does it print out the value of store on line 194?

Comment: Its printing "email:null"